# SUM (CASE WHEN) AS.. query

Tags: sql-server, case, sum

I'm very new to SQL and I'm trying and failing to get the right syntax on what I presumed would be a pretty easy query.

I have a table (CustomerSales) with four columns:

- `Period`: a combination of year and month, e.g. `201501` is January 2015;
- `Customer_no`;
- `Sales`;
- `Class`, i.e. customer segment.

I currently have the below query which extracts all sales in 2015 for class 'R', by customer number:

```
select Customer_no, class,
SUM (Sales) as '2015'
from CustomerSales
where left(Period,4) = '2015' and class = 'R'
Group by Customer_no, class
```

This returns a simple 3-column output of Customer_no, class and 2015 Sales.

I would like to add columns for each year in the table, i.e. add five more columns for each year 2010-2014.

To do this, I tried to move the `left(Period,4) = '2015'` expression into a `case when` condition and then my intention was to repeat this for 2014, 2013, etc. But the query fails before I even try to include the other years. The current query (with just 2015) is:

```
select Customer_no, class,
SUM (case when(left(Period,4) = '2015' then Sales else 0 end)) as '2015'
from CustomerSales
where class = 'R'
Group by Customer_no, class
```

The error I get is

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

I'd be grateful for any help as to how to fix the above query and add the 2010-2014 sales as extra columns.

Comment: Assuming your paste above is accurate, please review your parenthesis and make sure each open paren is matched by a close paren.  :)

Comment: Sorry, no it wasn't accurate. Even with the additional close paren. after 'end' I get the same error.

Comment: Have now edited original post

Comment: The correct location for the `)` is after `'2015'` .. `WHEN` doesn't require a `(` after it.  :) .. `SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(PERIOD,4) = '2015' THEN SALES ELSE 0 END)` or `SUM(CASE WHEN (LEFT(PERIOD,4) = '2015') THEN SALES ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Thanks Joishi. Did I mention I'm new to this ;-) Really appreciate the help

Comment: I would say that a case statement is an odd way to achieve this. Have you considered a sql pivot query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: @Peter: It's a CASE *expression*, not a CASE *statement*, and no, it's not odd. It's a perfectly normal way to do pivoting when the PIVOT syntax is unavailable (or if you just prefer this old-school technique). PIVOT makes it more elegant IMHO, but conditional aggregation is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: Pivot. Didn't even know that existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to balance your `()`.

Either delete the `(` between `when` and `left` or add a `)` after `'2015'`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Evan - much appreciated. All good now.